# Stop Net Browser Caching

Tags: c#, .net, caching, google-authentication

How do I stop the .NET browser, in my (C#) application, from caching information?

I'm using an embedded browser to log a user in; when they're logged out, it redirects them to their login page, instead of the blank login page.

With the google log in, you can click the top right, on your name, and then choose log in with different account, but this just adds more cached data (in the form of a second log in), and is not user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Browser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)` clears the cache.

It can be called before browser usage, so it feels like there was never any cached data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4tye44(v=vs.110).aspx